# connect to oracle database from an app running in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have a server where the oracle database is running (without docker). I currently develop a new java spring boot maven app that uses this database and should run on the same server. Building and running the jar on my windows pc works but if I want to run it in a docker container the db connection fails.

The url in the properties is `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/<sid>`, I use a putty tunnel to forward my local port to the server port.
The database is only accessible with `localhost:1521`, `<ip-adress>:1521` is not possible. I tried `-p 1521:1521` and `--network="host"` as options for `docker run ...` but both result in the same error.

So how do I make the app inside a docker container have access to a port on a server that is only accessible by a tunnel?
I'm very new to Docker, any help is greatly appreciated!

#### error:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743) ~[ojdbc-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666) ~[ojdbc-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32) ~[ojdbc-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566) ~[ojdbc-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:346) ~[tomcat-jdbc-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:227) ~[tomcat-jdbc-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:775) ~[tomcat-jdbc-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:703) ~[tomcat-jdbc-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:502) ~[tomcat-jdbc-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:153) ~[tomcat-jdbc-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:119) ~[tomcat-jdbc-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:132) ~[tomcat-jdbc-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
        at de.dsa.prodis.service.registry.Application.main(Application.java:20) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[registry-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[registry-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[registry-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[registry-service.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:470) ~[ojdbc-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:506) ~[ojdbc-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:595) ~[ojdbc-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:230) ~[ojdbc-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452) ~[ojdbc-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496) ~[ojdbc-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
        ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:161) ~[ojdbc-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:159) ~[ojdbc-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:428) ~[ojdbc-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
        ... 62 common frames omitted
```

### edit:

I got it running now but I'm not really sure if that's the way to go. To be clear: I'm running docker on my windows pc and the database on another server. The database is configured to only listen on localhost:1521, meaning I cannot change to connection string to use to actual ip adress of the server. That's why I have a tunnel from my pc (host of docker) to the server. The solution is to change the connection string to jdbc:oracle:thin:@host.docker.internal:1521/ (only for windows and mac)

Comment: you're having network configuration issues really - you shouldn't need to tunnel from the docker container to the host. I think your connection string should reference your hostname (the machine running docker) and then it is a matter of your running docker container being able to resolve that name. You need to look into the docker networking options - i think --network=“host” might be relevant?

Comment: @JohnXF thanks for your answer. I don't have a tunnel from docker to the host (my pc), I have a tunnel from my pc to the actual server the db is running on. Normally the apps (microservices) run on the same server as the db is, that's why the connection string contains localhost, but if I want to run one of those services locally on py pc, a tunnel is needed because the connection string cannot change. Same for my new app, it will run in docker on the same server as the db but for now I'm trying to run it on my pc. Thats why I need a connection from inside docker on my pc, to the server